# Como agrego una lista en una relacion muchos a muchos entity MVC5

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Intento agregar asociar una lista de subCategorias de libro a un libro
los modelos:

```
 public partial class Libro : Entidad
    {
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }
        public int? Ano { get; set; }
        public string Editorial { get; set; }
        public string Edicion { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string UsrCr { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaCr { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LibroFoto> LibroFotos { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategoria : Entidad
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public int? CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Libro> Libros { get; set; }
    }
```

El codigo del **`controller`** cuando intento crear un libro:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Titulo,Autor,ISBN,Descripcion,Precio,Ano,Editorial,Edicion,Cantidad,UsrCr,FechaCr")] Libro libro)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var listaSubCategorias = (IEnumerable<SubCategoria>)Session["SubCategoria"];
            libro.LibroFotos = (List<LibroFoto>)Session["Libro"];

            foreach (SubCategoria item in listaSubCategorias)
            {
                libro.SubCategorias.Add(item);
            }

            db.Libros.Add(libro);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            Session["SubCategoria"] = new List<SubCategoria>();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(libro);
    }
```

y el error en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias..!!

Answer (score 0):

Tu releación muchos a muchos está definida correctamente. el problema es que la sentencia `(IEnumerable<SubCategoria>)Session["SubCategoria"];` te está retornando nulo. Verifica que el valor donde guardas las sub categorías en el diccionario `Session` sea el mismo que estas usando para obtenerlas ("SubCategoria").

Para mayor información: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi el asunto,
Tenia q refacturar el constructor de las dos clases, de la siguiente forma:
class libro:

```
public partial class Libro : Entidad
{
    public Libro()
    {
        SubCategorias = new List<SubCategoria>();
    }

    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Autor { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    public int? Ano { get; set; }
    public string Editorial { get; set; }
    public string Edicion { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string UsrCr { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaCr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LibroFoto> LibroFotos { get; set; }
}
```

class SubCategoria

```
public class SubCategoria : Entidad
{
    public SubCategoria()
    {
        Libros = new List<Libro>();
    }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public int? CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Libro> Libros { get; set; }
}
```

de tal forma siempre resive una lista vacia de la relacion mochos a muchos.
muchas gracias amigos!